# form ajax return nothing

Tags: ajax, laravel

I try to understand where I made a mistake in my code , it works when I submit without ajax

When I am submitting my form with some empty fields my controller should return me some errors but it is returning nothing

Here is my js

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
});

var form = $('#register-lobby');

form.submit(function(e){
    console.log('click');
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax( {
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function( response ) {
            console.log(response);

        }
    });
});
```

My controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Game;
use App\Repository\LobbyRepository;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LobbyController extends Controller
{
    //
    private $r;
    /**
     * @var AuthManager
     */
    private $auth;

    public function __construct(LobbyRepository $r , AuthManager $auth)
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->r = $r;
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $games = Game::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
        return view('/lobby')->with('games', $games);
    }

    public function store(Request $request){

        $input = $request->all();
        $decription = $input['description'];
        $nb_player = $input['nb-players'];
        $link = $input['support-link'];
        $game_id = $input['game-id'];

        //return response()->json(['errors'=>'my errors']);

        $this->r->createLobby($decription , $nb_player , $link , $game_id ,$this->auth->user()->id);

    }

}
```

Which is weird is if I return an json response in my store method it works but if I do it in my Repository in createLobby I have no response and it should return a message

```
<?php
namespace App\Repository;


use App\Lobby;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class LobbyRepository {


    private $lobby;

    public function __construct(Lobby $lobby){
        $this->lobby = $lobby;
    }

    private function validator(array $data){
        $rules = [
            'description' => 'required|max:50',
            'link' => 'required|max:255',
        ];

        $messages = [
            'required' => 'Le champ :attribute est requis',
            'description.max' => 'La description est limitée à 50 caractères',
            'link.max' => 'Le lien est limité à 255 caractères',
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($data,$rules , $messages);
        return $validator;
    }

    public function createLobby($description , $nb_player ,$link , $game_id , $user_id){

        $validator = $this->validator(['description' => $description , 'link' => $link]);
        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json(['errors'=>'my errors']);
            /*
            dd($validator->errors());
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);
            */
        }
        else{
            return $this->lobby->newQuery()->create([
                'description' => $description,
                'support_link' => $link,
                'nb_player' => $nb_player,
                'game_id' => $game_id,
                'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                'user_id' => $user_id
            ]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you should return where you call the repository function,

return $this->r->createLobby($decription , $nb_player , $link , $game_id ,$this->auth->user()->id);

Comment: and also in better way you, better you return array data in repository and do $data = $this->r->f();

then return the json in controller,  return response()->json($data)

Comment: @Kelvin the missing return in my controller was the problem thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kelvin I missed the the return in my controller

```
  public function store(Request $request){

        $input = $request->all();
        $decription = $input['description'];
        $nb_player = $input['nb-players'];
        $link = $input['support-link'];
        $game_id = $input['game-id'];

        //return response()->json(['errors'=>'my errors']);

        return $this->r->createLobby($decription , $nb_player , $link , $game_id ,$this->auth->user()->id);

    }
```